# Dynamic Validation with nested form

Tags: javascript, angular, nested-forms

I'm trying to create a nested form with dynamic validation. There's the parent component (`finalizaNegociacao`) which hold the nested forms (`dadosTitular`). On the nested form I have a checkbox (`handleType`) that changes the validation of some fields, like `cpf`. What should be happening is: When I click on the checkbox `cpf`is no longer a **required** field. But even if I click on it it still required. Can someone help me? 
Here's the code:

**FinalizaNegociacao (parent component)**, the main logic here is in the `recebeValidators` :

```
export class FinalizaNegociacaoComponent implements OnInit, OnChanges  {
  public dados:dadosAcordo;
  public formDadosBancarios: FormGroup;
  public submitted: boolean; 
  public events: any[] = []; 
  public servError:any;
  public servSuccess:any;  
  cpf_REGEXP =  /^\d+$/;

  constructor(private _fb: FormBuilder, private finalizaAcordo:FinalizaNegociacaoService) {} 

  ngOnInit() {  
    this.formDadosBancarios = this._fb.group({
      id: [''],
      dados_titular: this._fb.array([
        this.initTitular()
      ])
    })      
  }

  initTitular(){
    return this._fb.group({
      titular: ['', [<any>Validators.required, <any>Validators.minLength(3)]],
      cnpj: [''],
      cpf: ['', <any>Validators.required],
      data_nasc: [''],
      agencia: ['', <any>Validators.required ],
      banco: ['', <any>Validators.required],
      conta: ['', <any>Validators.required],
      tipo:  ['', <any>Validators.required],
      pessoa_juridica: ['']
    })
  }

  addTitular(){
    const control = <FormArray> this.formDadosBancarios.controls['dados_titular'];
    control.push(this.initTitular());
  }

  recebeValidators(e:any){
      let array = <FormArray> this.formDadosBancarios.get('dados_titular');
      let cpf = array.at(0).get("cpf");
      let cpfCtrl = this.formDadosBancarios.get(['dados_titular',0,'cpf']);
      let cnpj = array.at(0).get('cnpj');
      let data_nasc = array.at(0).get('data_nasc');
      cpfCtrl = e;
      console.log(cpfCtrl);
  }
```

**DadosTitular, (Child component)**, the main logic here is the `handleType`:

```
export class TitularComponent {
    // we will pass in address from App component
    @Input('group')
    public titularForm: FormGroup;

    @Output() modelChanged = new EventEmitter();
    public formDadosBancarios: FormGroup;
    cpf_REGEXP =  /^\d+$/;

    constructor(private _fb: FormBuilder, private finalizaAcordo:FinalizaNegociacaoService) {} 

    ngOnInit() {  
      this.formDadosBancarios = this._fb.group({
        id: [''],
        dados_titular: this._fb.array([
          this.initTitular()
        ])
      })      
    }

    initTitular(){
        return this._fb.group({
            titular: ['', [<any>Validators.required, <any>Validators.minLength(3)]],
            cnpj: [''],
            cpf: ['', <any>Validators.required],
            data_nasc: [''],
            agencia: ['', <any>Validators.required ],
            banco: ['', <any>Validators.required],
            conta: ['', <any>Validators.required],
            tipo:  ['', <any>Validators.required],
            pessoa_juridica: ['']
        })
    }

    handleType(isJuridica: boolean, i:number, e:any): void {
      let array = <FormArray> this.formDadosBancarios.get('dados_titular');
      let cpf = array.at(0).get("cpf");
      let cnpj = array.at(0).get('cnpj');
      let data_nasc = array.at(0).get('data_nasc');
      const cpfCtrl = this.formDadosBancarios.get(['dados_titular',0,'cpf']);
      const cnpjCtrl = this.formDadosBancarios.get(['dados_titular',0, 'cnpj']);
      const data_nascCtrl = this.formDadosBancarios.get(['dados_titular',0,'data_nasc']);
      const reqValidators: ValidatorFn[] = [Validators.required, Validators.pattern(this.cpf_REGEXP)];
      if (isJuridica) {
        cpfCtrl.setValidators(null);
        data_nascCtrl.setValidators(null);
        cnpjCtrl.setValidators(reqValidators);
        this.modelChanged.emit(cpfCtrl);
      }else{
        cpfCtrl.setValidators(reqValidators);
        data_nascCtrl.setValidators(reqValidators)
        cnpjCtrl.setValidators(null);
        this.modelChanged.emit(cpfCtrl);
      }
      cpfCtrl.updateValueAndValidity();
      data_nascCtrl.updateValueAndValidity();
      cnpjCtrl.updateValueAndValidity();

    }
}
```

and there's the html:

```
<div formArrayName="dados_titular">
        <div *ngFor="let dados_titular of formDadosBancarios.controls.dados_titular.controls; let i=index">
          <div [formGroupName]="i">
            <titular (modelChanged)="recebeValidators($event)" [group]="formDadosBancarios.controls.dados_titular.controls[i]"></titular>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Comment: Have you tried `control.clearValidators()` and `setValidators`?

Comment: yes, in fact setValidators(null) used to work before I turned the form into a nested form. I think the problem is about the parent/child components

Comment: Where do you use `titularForm`? Why does your child component create new `formGroup`?

Comment: I need to create the formGroup so `handleType` can work since `handeType`deals with form elements.

Comment: `titularForm`is what I'm using to show error messages from validation on the html code